# update directly in the same page php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

i have this code in update.php:

```
public function update($segment,$id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE `segments` SET `segment` = '$segment' WHERE `id` = '$id'") or die($this->conn->error);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            $this->conn->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and in home.php i have this:

```
 <table   class = "table table-bordered table-responsive  ">
            <thead>

                <th>Segment</th>

                <th>Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

                require 'class.php';

                $conn = new db_class();
                $read = $conn->read();
                while($fetch = $read->fetch_array()){ 

            ?>
                <tr>

                                        <td  contenteditable="true"><?php echo $fetch['segment']?></td>

                            <form action="activate.php" method="post" name="segment"> 
             <textarea style="display: none;" name="segment" id="markup"></textarea>                    
                                   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo  $fetch['id']  ;?>">

                                   <td><center><button class = "btn btn-default" name="update"><a href=""></a><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button> | <button class = "btn btn-success" type="submit" name="activate"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate</button> | <button class = "btn btn-danger" name="deactivate"><a href=""></a><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> deactivate</button></center></td>
                            </form>
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i set the  to contenteditable="true" to update directly from the same page,

and in activate i did this:

```
<?php 
require_once 'class.php';

if(ISSET($_POST['update'])){
    $segment =$_POST['segment'];

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $conn = new db_class();
    $conn->activate($segment, $id);
    echo '
        <script>alert("Updated Successfully")</script>;

    ';
}
```

?>

so in js i tried this:

```
$('#work_form').submit(function(){
// Update the DOM
var block_1 = $('#block_1', '#work_form');
block_1.find('input').each(function(i,e){
    el = $(e);
    el.attr('value', el.val());
});
// Snatch the markup
var markup = block_1.html(); 
// Place it into the textarea
$('#markup', '#work_form').html( markup );
// Move on
return true;
```

});

when i try to update and i did echo to the query to see i got this:

```
UPDATE `segments` SET `segment` = '' WHERE `id` = '5'
```

any help would be great, thank u so much

Comment: In your HTML, I cannot see any input field with name as segment. Thats why you are getting this undefined index.

Comment: i dont need any input field, i just want to edit from the same page, i just make the td tag contenteditable="true" so i can change the value but how to save it in database when i click update @DineshPatra

Comment: understand this, when you submit a form, only data from input, textarea, select  tag  will be submitted. The list of form elements https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp.

Though you made td as content editable, it will be not submitted.

Comment: But to do this, you can submit the data via ajax,
or
You can create a textare whose display is none. Then on formsubmit, via javascript, copy the innerHTML of td tag to the textarea. Insted of naming the td tag as segment, name textarea as segment.

Comment: im not particular with javascript, can u tell me how? please? thank u @DineshPatra

Comment: Chek the answer

Answer (score 1):

Please use ajax ,or make your input tag in some form element.
for ajax

```
var segmant  = $('#id_of_TD').html();
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'services/session/token',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: {
                                'segmant': segmant
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                         alert('Form is submitted successfully')
                    }
                });
```

Add js file before code and change url to your page name.

Answer (score 0):

Code for **home.php**

```
<?php 
require 'class.php';
$conn = new db_class();
$read = $conn->read();
$data = [];
while($fetch = $read->fetch_array()){ 
    $data[] = $fetch;
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <table   class = "table table-bordered table-responsive ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Segment</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($data as $fetch): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="segment" contenteditable="true"><?= $fetch['segment'] ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button class = "btn btn-default action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" data-action="update"> 
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update
                            </button> 
                            | 
                            <button class = "btn btn-success action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>" type="submit" data-action="activate">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Activate
                            </button> 
                            | 
                            <button class = "btn btn-danger action-btn" data-id="<?= $fetch['id'] ?>"  data-action="deactivate">
                                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> deactivate
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".action-btn").on("click", function(e) {
                var id      = $(this).attr("data-id");
                var segment = $(this).parents("tr").find("td.segment").html();
                var action  = $(this).attr("data-action");
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "action.php",
                    "method": "post",
                    "data": {
                        "id":      id,
                        "segment": segment,
                        "action":  action
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code change the url for bootstrap.min.css as per your project structure.

Now do not use activate.php file.
create a new file action.php, and add following code.

```
<?php 

# If there is no action exit
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    exit;
}

$action = $_POST['action'];
$segment =$_POST['segment'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

switch($action) {
    case "update":
        $conn = new db_class();
        $conn->activate($segment, $id);
        echo "Updated success fully.";
        exit;
    case "activate":
        # Code for activate
    case "deactivate":
        # Code for deactivate

}

?>
```

Try this. This is done via ajax. Here I have done only for update function.

Comment: i tried this and not working so i just tried to use javascript but i have this error if u can help it would be great @

Comment: update works thank u, can u tell how to do the activate and deactivate? @di

Comment: see the action.php, there is a case for activate. write your code for activate there, just like update.